# consuming RESTful api with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, restful-architecture

I have a backbone application and a RESTful api.  I used the sample created by Coenraets to understand the architecture of a backbone app, but I decided to setup my own structure and just use the data for testing.

I want to know the best way to return data from the RESTful api.  I currently have my app folder structure setup with model, collection, view and service folders.  I have a node server running with express that handles the backend and is working fine.

What I want to know is what is the best practice for accessing the restful data api?  Should I do that in my service class or in my view class?  How do I make this work dynamically using the returned data from my restful api:  `http://localhost:3000/employees`

It seems like there are many ways to do this and for now I just want something that works, but eventually I do want to know what is the best way to do it.  Ultimately I want to have a CRUD setup. But I'm not sure where that should be setup.  Similar to what is detailed here: `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797899/BackBone-Tutorial-Part-CRUD-Operations-on-Backbone`

My files are as follows:

employeecolletion.js

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Employee = require('../models/employeemodel.js');

module.exports = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Employee,
    url:"http://localhost:3000/employees"
});
```

employeemodel.js

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var EmployeeCollection = require('../collections/employeecollection.js');

module.exports = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot:"http://localhost:3000/employees" 

    // initialize:function () {
    //     this.reports = new EmployeeCollection();
    //     //this.reports.url = this.urlRoot + "/" + 1 + "/reports";

    // }

});
```

employee.js (employee view that binds to my template)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var base = require('./base.js');
var EmployeeList = require('../collections/employeecollection.js');
var employeeService = require('../services/employeeService.js');
var template = fs.readFileSync('app/templates/employee.mu', { encoding: 'utf8' });


module.exports = base.extend({
  el: '.view',
  template:template,
  collection: employeeService.collection,

  initialize: function () {
    this.viewModel = {
      employee_list: this.collection.toJSON()
      //employee_list: this.collection.fetch() --HERE I EXPERIMENTED WITH FETCHING THE DATA
    };
    this.render();
  }
});
```

employeeservice.js (file in service folder that would ideally return the collection which I would just bind to my template in they employees view file)

```
var EmployeeCollection = require('../collections/employeecollection.js');

//if wanting to pass in data manually
var employee_list = [
    {
        id:1,
        firstName:"James",
        lastName:"King",
        fullName:"James King",
        managerId:0,
        managerName:"",
        title:"President and CEO",
        department:"Corporate",
        cellPhone:"617-000-0001",
        officePhone:"781-000-0001",
        email:"jking@fakemail.com",
        city:"Boston, MA",
        pic:"james_king.jpg",
        twitterId:"@fakejking",
        blog:"http://coenraets.org"
    }
];

//HERE I WAS EXPERIMENTING WITH A DIFFERENT SYNTAX TO DO THE FILTERING BY ID
//IN MY SERVICE AND SIMPLY RETURNING THE FINAL DATA I WANT TO MY VIEW CLASS

// var employees = new EmployeeCollection({id: id});

//  employees.fetch({
//      success: function (data) {
//          console.log(data);
//      }
//  });


module.exports = {
  collection: new EmployeeCollection(employee_list)
};
```

Comment: I don't know much about making custom api's, but most api's that I have used are just collected and organized in json objects.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone is meant for RESTful services.

I'll try to explain the basics using some easy to understand terms.

So backbone is based on models and views.

The **model** is responsible to the data.
That means, that the model is the one who fetches the data from the server and stores it.
In an interactive application, the model should have a `url` or `urlRoot` properties which indicate what is the url of the specific resource this model refers to.
For example, if we had a Person resource, and assuming we are consuming a standard RESTfult service, I would expect something similiar to this:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url :   'http://localhost:3000/api/Person'
});
```

That actually lets us create new instances of this model and manipulate it.
This url will be used by the model for all CRUD operations related to it.

For example, if we now create a new instance:

`var person = new Person();`

We now have the following basic CRUD operations:

**fetch**: this method is executing an async AJAX `GET` request behind the scenes, and injects the data into the model.
Now, after we fetched the data, we can use it by simply calling `get`:
`person.get('name');` * assuming there's a `name` property.

**save** this method is exectuing an async AJAX `POST` or `PUT` request behind the scene.
If the model's `idAttribute` is undefined, it will executed `POST`, otherwise `PUT`. The idAttribute is a model property which indicates what is the model's unique id.

A sample usage:

```
person.set({name : 'Mor'});
person.save();
```

The abvoe will execute a post request with the `name: 'Mor'` in the request body.
If for example I fetched the model, and already have an `idAttribute` assigned, calling the same `save` method will use the `PUT` request.

**destroy** this method will execute a `DELETE` request behind the scene.
Sample usage: `person.destroy();`.

Obviously I have just shown you the basic usages, there's a lot more options out there.

A **collection** is simply a list of models so there's not much to explain, you can read more here: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection

A **view** is all you see. It is the visual part of the application.
What Backbone lets us do, is to bind views to models and collections.
By that, we can create some dynamic content and visuals.

A basic view would like something like that:

```
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.person',
    initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html("hello :"+this.model.get("name"));
  }
});
```

As you can see, I used `listenTo`. It is an event listener that calls `render` each time the model changes.
When I refer to `this.model` I refer to a model I will pass to the view when I initiate it:

`var view = new View({ model : person});`

By that, and since I used `listenTo`, my view is now binded with the `person` model.

This is basically it. 
Obviously, there's **a lot** more to learn and understand, but this pretty much covers the basics.

Please refer to http://backbonejs.org/ and read some more information.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  It helps break things down.  But what happens when I use the following line of code in my employeeservice.js file: collection: `new EmployeeCollection().fetch()`. I expect it to return data from my api using the get call and assign it to a collection.  In my employee.js file, I should then have a collection that is assigned to my viewmodel in the initialize function.  But this is not working.  I'm getting no errors, but my template is not binding to the data I am expecting from the fetch call.

Comment: I basically want to return a collection from they employeeservice.js class so that it can be assigned to the viewModel in the employee.js view.

Comment: After doing a lot of researching it seems like the post here answers my question: https://dzone.com/articles/backbonejs-parsing-response.  Unless I'm missing something, the fetch call on a backbone collection returns an html response object that has to be parsed.  So I don't think I can use the syntax provided above by MorKadosh.  Is that correct?  When I try that syntax, my fetch indeed returns the following response object.

Comment: Response object I get:  `Object { readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: [16]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: [16]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: [16]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: [16]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: [16]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.statusCode(), abort: [16]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.abort(), state: [16]</</<.Deferred/promise.state(), always: [16]</</<.Deferred/promise.always(), then: [16]</</<.Deferred/promise.then(), 8 more… }`

Comment: In my response object there is a responseJSON key that has responseJSON object that has the values from my Api that I want to bind to my template.